# Block a file from being accessed over the internet

Tags: firewalls

I keep my client data in a password protected Excel file.

For added security, I would like to block access to this file from potential hackers on the Internet.

Is it possible to block access to a file from the internet?

I can only see how to block a program with Windows Firewall, not an individual file.

Comment: Is this file just available on the internet for everyone? Like on a public webserver? I'm assuming this is just a file on your desktop. So unless they have access to your system they should not be able to access it.

Comment: keep it on a thumb drive that you take with you or put in your desk overnight/on weekends.

Answer (score 2):

The file is not going to be accessible over the Internet. There is nothing offering the file to remote people.

What can happen, though, is that someone can hack in and gain access to your computer, and from that level of access, gain access to any file on your computer.

The most important protection for this is to do exactly what you have done: encrypt and password protect the file.

As an additional measure, you could store the file on a removable drive and disconnect the drive when you do not need access to the file yourself. This is not as secure as it sounds because once you connect the drive, then anyone who has hacked into your computer could then also access the file. But it is an additional measure.

Comment: That's good to hear. I will do as you suggest and keep it on a removable drive and only connect it when I need to edit it. Or do you think keeping the file on my Google Drive or OneDrive would be more secure?